# Different Output while having same input

Tags: python, pycharm

```
groceries = {'fruits', 'milk', 'sweet', 'egg'}

print(groceries)
```

When I runs the code, it shows following different output randomly.

I want to know that why it shows different output of same input ?

**Different Output**

Sometime output is this:

```
{'milk', 'sweet', 'fruits', 'egg'}
```

Sometime output is this:

```
{'sweet', 'fruits', 'milk', 'egg'}
```

Sometime output is this:

```
{'egg', 'sweet', 'fruits', 'milk'}
```

Sometime Output is this:

```
{'fruits', 'milk', 'sweet', 'egg'}
```

I want to know what is the reason, why it shows different output and randomly?

How we can show single output each time?

Comment: Because dictionaries are **unoredred** in Python. There are no guarantees how a dictionary is structured.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can we make order?

Comment: there is an [`OrderedDict(..)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem He did not create a dictionary but a set. Sets are also not ordered. For dictionaries this is BTW not true anymore in the most recent Python versions.

Comment: @KlausD.: yeah indeed. both sets and dicts are unoredered.

Comment: use a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html) or [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Why aren't you using a list?

Comment: @KlausD. nevertheless, [as stated in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation) it is an implementation detail that should not be relied on, and one should use `OrderedDict` anyway...

Comment: @khelwood maybe they don't want duplicates and they want O(l) member testing, but probably you're right and they just don't understand python data structures

Comment: WillemVanOnsem and klaus thanks. @khelwood i am doing tutorials about sets, i don't know about dictionary. I am wondering and wants to know what is the reason of different output, so Willem answer me that is is unoredred.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote? I am a bit clueless what should be wrong with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You defined a set, which is unordered. You might use tuple or lists instead:

```
groceries = ['fruits', 'milk', 'sweet', 'egg'] # list
groceries = ('fruits', 'milk', 'sweet', 'egg') # tuple
```

Also there is an [ordered version](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) of the dictionary.

Comment: As Klaus D. already pointed out, the OP created a set, not dict.